# Is it possible to use MaskedTextBox to accept the input in HexaDecimal format?

Tags: c#, user-controls

Is it possible to use MaskedTextBox for accepting user input in hexadecimal format? The normal solutions are like accepting the key inputs and discard if it's not a allowed character. Are there any other approaches?

Answer (score 1):

No, the MaskedTextBox can't be used to restrict the input to hexadecimal through use of the mask but any textbox could be used by attaching an event handler to the KeyUp (or KeyPress) event. The handler can then check the typed character against the hex set ([0-9a-fA-F]) and reject the press if not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change the type of box, make it string and then reformat the string into hex.

Answer (score 0):

```
private: System::Void maskedTextBox1_KeyPress(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::KeyPressEventArgs^  e) 
         {
             String^ temp = "012345679abcdefABCDEF";
             if (temp->IndexOf(e->KeyChar) == -1)
             {
                 e->Handled = true;
             }
         }
```

use this for hex char control.